# Error using jquery trigger with multi section file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample html

```js
$('.do_uploadFile').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".upload_section").find(".uploadFile").click();
});
$('.uploadFile').on('change', function() {
  // ... code upload file
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="upload_section">
  <input type="button" value="Choose file(s)" class="do_uploadFile">
  <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" class="uploadFile" multiple="multiple">
</form>

<form class="upload_section">
  <input type="button" value="Choose file(s)" class="do_uploadFile">
  <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" class="uploadFile" multiple="multiple">
</form>

<form class="upload_section">
  <input type="button" value="Choose file(s)" class="do_uploadFile">
  <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" class="uploadFile" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

When I click Choose file(s), it's work for first upload_section, not work for 2nd, 3rd,...how to fix it

[image: upload]

Comment: I tried your code and it is uploading files at correct uploader. Did you mean that you are having issue when you post such files to server?

Comment: I just show capture image preview below

Comment: You mean that there is an issue in preview? then you will need to show code for same.

Comment: I was find ideas for this problem by using each function